# Display right text color according to segment?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control with 2 segments `ONC` and `OFC`, if I change color of `row1` under `ONC`, it is changing color of `row1` in `OFC` as well. I like to change text color to `green` for an event, if `eventStatus = 1`, and `red` if the `eventStatus = 2`. This is what I have done so far

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    let eventDesc = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EventDec", into: context) as! EventDec
    var eventSchOnc: EventScheduleOnc?
    var eventSchOfc: EventScheduleOfc?
    do {
        switch (eventSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex)
        {
        case 0:
             let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventScheduleOnc")
             fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
             fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventNameOnc == %@", self.oncEvents[indexPath.row] as String)
             var objects: [EventScheduleOnc]
             try objects = context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [EventScheduleOnc]
             eventSchOnc = objects[0] as EventScheduleOnc
             break

        case 1:
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventScheduleOfc")
            fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
            fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventNameOfc == %@", self.ofcEvents[indexPath.row] as String)
            var objects: [EventScheduleOfc]
            try objects = context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [EventScheduleOfc]
            eventSchOfc = objects[0] as EventScheduleOfc
            break
        default:break
        }
    }

catch {
        print("Try Again")
      }

    eventDesc.setValue(eventSchOnc, forKey: "eventScheduleOnc")
    eventDesc.setValue(eventSchOfc, forKey: "eventScheduleOfc")

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "msg", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "yes", style: .default) { _ in
        eventDesc.setValue(1, forKey: "eventStatus")
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch{ 
            print("Try again") 
        } 
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .default) { _ in
        eventDesc.setValue(2, forKey: "eventStatus")
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch { 
            print("Try again") 
        } 
    })
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let myEventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell
    let eventDescOnc = self.eventScheduleOnc[indexPath.row].eventDecOnc
    let eventOnc = eventDescOnc?.eventStatus
    if (eventOnc == 1) {
        myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
    }
    else if (eventOnc == 2){
        myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

    let eventDescOfc = self.eventScheduleOfc[indexPath.row].eventDecOfc
    let eventOfc = eventDescOfc?.eventStatus
    if (eventOfc == 1) {
        myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
    }
    else if (eventOfc == 2) {
        myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

How do I display right text colors according to `eventStatus` under each `segment`?

Comment: What if you haven't set the `eventStatus` value with `EventScheduleOnc` or `EventScheduleOfc`? Means for the first time, what color you will show for that?

Comment: Just black text color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using String array used array of `EventScheduleOfc` and `EventScheduleONc` and after you set `eventStatus` of `EventDesc` in `didSelectRowAt` simply reload the tableView.

```
private func eventDataOnc(){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventScheduleOnc")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do
    {            
        self.eventScheduleOnc = try context.fetch(request) as! [EventScheduleOnc]
    }
    catch{}
}

private func eventDataOfc(){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventScheduleOfc")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do
    {
        self.eventScheduleOfc = try context.fetch(request) as! [EventScheduleOfc]
    }
    catch{}
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let myEventCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

    if eventSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        myEventCell.eventLabel.text = self.eventScheduleOnc[indexPath.row].eventNameOnc

        if let eventDesc = self.eventScheduleOnc[indexPath.row].eventDec,           
           let eventStatus = eventDesc.eventStatus {
            if eventStatus == 1 {
                myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
            }
            else {
                myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
        else {
            myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }
    else {
        myEventCell.eventLabel.text  = self.eventScheduleOfc[indexPath.row].eventNameOfc
        if let eventDesc = self.eventScheduleOfc[indexPath.row].eventDec,           
           let eventStatus = eventDesc.eventStatus {
            if eventStatus == 1 {
                myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
            }
            else {
                myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
        else {
            myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }
    return myEventCell
}
```

Now in `didSelect` simply set the value in core data and then instead of setting `textColor` of label simply reload the `tableView`.

Comment: Works perfectly :)

Comment: @Coder221 Welcome mate :)